# making a user profile page in meteor

Tags: meteor

I'm fairly new to meteor and am trying to figure out how to go about creating a user profile page that can be seen by other users and edited by the owner. In my current app the packages that I'm currently using for accounts are accounts-password, useraccounts:materialize, and useraccounts:iron-routing.

I have a page set up already for the profile but can't figure out how to get the data there. I've found other "tutorials" and guides but none clearly point out what I'm aiming to accomplish.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: i guess you need to study more to get the grip of meteor. what you can do for a starter, is to read `your first meteor application` book. it's free to read online.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One easy and recommended way to accomplish this task would be creating a helper for profile and then displaying those data in the blaze. the logged in user's data is published by default. what you can do is something like below

```
Template.templateName.helpers({
    userData : function(){ return Meteor.user() };
});
```

and then in the blaze use this helper

```
{{#with userData}}
    Name: {{profile.name}}
    ... rest of the data here.
{{/with}}
```

Comment: Thanks for your speedy reply. I'm going to check out the book you suggested as well. Does this solution work the same if I add my own fields to the users collection?